# forward slashes in split command

Tags: javascript, split

I was comparing my code to someone else's code on CoderByte and I understood everything he did besides one minor thing in Line 2 when he did a split command to split the argument which goes into the parameter str by spaces via (/ /) rather than (" ").

Why was he able to use forward slashes and what would be the reason to do so?

Here's his code:

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
  var words = str.split(/ /);
  str = '';
  for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
    if (str != '') str += ' ';
    str += word;
  }
  // code goes here  
  return str;     
}
console.log(LetterCapitalize("Argument goes here"))
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/ is a special character in Javascript that indicates a regular expression match, in this case splitting on matches to a regular expression.

For example:

```
var arr = "1,2x3x4".split(/[x,]/);
```

Will give you an array of `[1,2,3,4]` - in this case the regular expression results in a split when an "x" or "," is found.